# public ip across ipsec vpn tunnel

Tags: cisco, routing, vpn, tunnel

two sites connected ip sec vpn tunnel. site A has 16 static ip addresses for outside to in access (NAT). can I route one of my public ip addresses from site A across vpn tunnel to a host on site B?

Comment: Please show your device configuration as well as your device models and versions. Right now it is unclear what you are asking. Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can advertise any of your networks (individual IPv4 addresses can be advertised as `/32` networks) across the tunnel, assuming you are running a routing protocol with the router on the other end of the tunnel. It is routing protocols that advertise your networks. Routers learn routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Through dynamic routing protocols

Since the router on the other end of the tunnel is not directly connected to your network, option 1 is out.

The router on the other end of the tunnel could be statically configured with the network.

You could run a routing protocol with the router on the other end of the network and advertise any or all networks you have.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can.  You simply use your NAT/PAT in the ordinary way.  It doesn't matter that the inside address isn't local to the NAT router; you have to ensure that the routers at both sites have a router down the tunnel for the internal addresses at the other site.